# Using Hydrogen with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, atom-editor, hydrogen

The default version of python installed on my mac is python 2. I also have python 3 installed but can't install python 2.

I'd like to configure Hyrdrogen on Atom to run my script using python 3 instead.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `jupyter kernelspec list --json` to view the current kernels installed on your machine. The `python3` kernelspec `argv` key should have a valid path to your Python 3 executable. If it does not, you need to modify your kernel to point to the correct executable.

Instead of manually editing the kernelspec, I'd recommend reinstalling the kernel using one of the commands [described here](https://nteract.io/kernels), depending on whether you use conda, virtualenv, or no virtual environment.

Also, make sure to start atom from a terminal using `atom .`, as they recommend in the atom docs, to ensure that atom has the same environment as your terminal.

Comment: Yes, Python 2.7 is the version it points to when I enter my terminal and type 'python'.

How do I change it so that the default version is python 3?

Comment: @ExpertShaun I updated my comment some. You should google "how to add python 3 to path" since it varies by system and there are tons of tutorials on that kind of thing.

Comment: This isn't a PATH setting... You should rather edit the kernel that Hydrogen is using

Answer (score 0):

I used `jupyter kernelspec list` and I found 2 kernels available, one for python2 and another for python3

So I pasted python3 kernel folder in the same directory where python2 ken=rnel is installed and removed python2 kernel using 'rm -rf python2'